# PHP : Save Array into $_SESSION

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have a Login form with Array as a success result.

If User input right credentials, then the system will have output like this :

```
 Array ( [error] => false 
         [name] => admin 
         [email] => admin@baru.com 
         [apiKey] => e96d4538f1dea6b0bc16468e10191336 
         [status] =>actived 
         [createdAt] => 2014-11-08 16:31:14 )
```

How to save each array value into $_SESSION like this ?

```
$_SESSION['name'] = $Name;
$_SESSION['apiKey'] = $apiKey;
```

etc..

How to do it ?

What's the best approach?
Thanks for any help :)

Comment: `$_SESSION = array_merge($_SESSION, $yourArray);` could work.

Comment: Keeping all these together as their related array in $_SESSION is probably wise.  `$_SESSION['login'] = $that_array;` will group them under `$_SESSION['login']['name'], $_SESSION['login']['apikey']` etc...

Comment: solved guys:) thanks for your help. sorry if my question is duplicate. I'm new here